# Windows Command to identify folders with only one file

Tags: batch-file, command-line-interface

I need a command to run from the Windows CLI to identify any folders (or sub folders) that contain only one file. If the folder contains two files, it should not be included. In the end, I need to output this list to a text file. It should contain the full folder path.

Ex: OutputLog.txt

`C:\fold1
C:\fold1\sub
C:\fold3
C:\fold4`

Comment: do you have a parent folder or a list of folders?

Comment: if a folder contains one folder and one file should be included in the output?

Answer (score 1):

This should work to identify folders with one file.

```
@echo off
for /d /r "d:\base\folder" %%a in (*) do (
    dir /b /a-d "%%a" 2>nul |find /c /v "" |findstr "^1$" >nul && >>file.txt echo %%a
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /D /R %%a in (*) do (
   set count=0
   for %%b in ("%%a\*.*") do set /A count+=1
   if !count! equ 1 echo %%a
)) > OutputLog.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

set "parentfolder=c:\test"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%F in ('dir /s /a:d /b "%parentfolder%"') do (
    dir "%%F"|findstr /b "1 File(s)" >nul 2>&1 && echo %%F
)
```

This will list all subfolders with only one file in a parent folder .As it checks the string of the dir command output it should be altered if language settings/windows version provide different `DIR` command output.

Comment: Your code will fail if there are 11 or 21 or 31 files etc.

Comment: @foxidrive Thanks . Fixed. Will also fail if there is a file named `1 File(s)` which is a valid file name :-D